# Solving exponential function with linear and quadratic term

Tags: exponential-function

I came along this equation in a book for higher education engineering:

$$ x\cdot2^x - x^2 = 135 $$
What I know is that there are ways to get a solution numerically. But I‘m pretty sure that there is also an analytical way (besides rather complicated stuff like lamberts function) since the result is (simply) $$ x=5$$
Did I miss a simple trick?

Best wishes!

Comment: The trick is probably just to guess and check.

Comment: Oh man! I mean, this would be disappointing

Comment: Let $f(x)$= LHS - RHS : it is an increasing function with a unique explicited root $x=5$. Why would you need an analytic expression ? If we replace now $135$ by $134$, besides a possible expression with Lambert $W$ function, I am almost sure there is no analytic expression of the root.

Comment: Well, $$2^5-5^2=7$$ $$2^7+2^5-5^2=2^7+7=135$$ $$(2^2+1)2^5-5^2=135$$ $$5\cdot 2^5-5^2=135$$ I guess that doesn't really help, although it might be obvious to someone who thinks in binary. Note that $x\cdot 2^x-135=x^2$, so $x\cdot 2^x\ge135$, which pretty quickly leads to $x>4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is an upgrade over guessing but you can try this,

$x(2^x -x) = 135$

The factors of $135$ are $1 \times 135 , 3 \times 45,5 \times 27,9 \times 15$
so now you have a guess at x, So check for $(2^x -x)$ and at $x = 5 ,$ we get $(2^x -x) = 27$

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about integer factorization of 135 too. Maybe, this is a mathematical way of guessing here. Thanks!

Comment: Yes but this is not scalable

Comment: Yeah, you’re definitely right man!